# Reading from keychain failed with error: 'No keychain service available'

Tags: arch-linux, gnu, gnome-keyring, lxqt

```
System:    Host: MyComputer Kernel: 4.8.14-gnu-1 x86_64 (64 bit)
           Desktop: LXQt Distro: Parabola GNU/Linux-libre
```

My owncloud client does not start automatically.
I know, nextcloud is what I should use, but I'm right now stuck with owncloud and I doubt that it solves the problem I'm having right now.

The error:

[image]

I have qtkeychain installed, but I'm not sure if that's a keychain service.

```
$ sudo pacman -Ss keychain
extra/keychain 2.8.3-1
    A front-end to ssh-agent, allowing one long-running ssh-agent process per system, rather than per login
community/envoy 14-2
    A ssh-agent/gpg-agent keychain and process monitor
community/qtkeychain 0.7.0-1 [installed]
    Provides support for secure credentials storage
```

I also have two keyring apps installed.

```
$ sudo pacman -Ss keyring
libre/parabola-keyring 20161215-1 [installed]
    Parabola GNU/Linux-libre PGP keyring
core/archlinux-keyring 20161201-1 [installed]
    Arch Linux PGP keyring
```

So I wonder what has to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by installing gnome-keyring.

I bleieve the reason is due to parabola-keyring and archlinux-keyring being used for pacman repos and not applications and there is no lxqt-keyring in existance, so gnome-keyring will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

One might also try installing `libgnome-keyring0` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/6500). The `gnome-keyring` package was not enough under Ubuntu 18.04.